# Which side of the conflict in Syria used child soldiers?

Tags: iran, syria, war-crime

According to Iranwire, the practice of child soldiers / martyrs is still happening in the region of the levant, namely in Syria:

> Although the practice is most often associated the Iran-Iraq War,
> there is evidence of children taking part in more recent conflicts
> too, including the war in Syria. ([source](https://iranwire.com/en/features/64724/))

Which side of the conflict (if at all) used child soldiers in Syria? Were there any Iranian connection, or was it an independent phenomenon?

Answer (score 3):

IDK about Iranian militias specifically in this case, but actually the US-allied SDF has been [accused](https://apnews.com/article/syria-child-recruitment-d4d48148e0b04e5649aa43f540988ace) of doing this too:

> The number of children recruited by armed groups in Syria has risen steadily over the past three years — from 813 in 2020 to 1,296 in 2021 and 1,696 in 2022, the U.N. says.
>
> Among those allegedly recruiting children is a U.S. ally in the battle against Islamic State extremists — the Kurdish-led Syrian Democratic Forces, according to the U.N. In 2022, the U.N. attributed more than a third of the cases, or 637, to the SDF and associated groups in northeast Syria. [...]
>
> In 2019, the SDF signed an agreement with the U.N. promising to end the enlistment of children younger than 18 and set up a number of child protection offices in its area. The U.S. State Department defended its ally in a statement, saying, that the SDF “is the only armed actor in Syria to respond to the UN’s call to end the use of child soldiers.”

And the Turkish-allied militias too:

> The report also said the U.N. had confirmed 611 recruitment cases by the Turkish-backed Syrian National Army, which has clashed with the SDF in the past, and 383 by the al-Qaida-linked Hayat Tahrir al Sham in northwest Syria. The report cited 25 cases of child recruitment by Syrian government forces and pro-government militias.

OTOH the UN might not be in much of a position to investigate children sent from Iran. Which HRW reported some cases thereof [in 2017 at least](https://www.hrw.org/news/2017/11/30/irans-child-soldiers-syria).

> “Thirteen years – thirteen years old!” the interviewer repeats, proudly, as the camera pans upward to the grinning, bearded faces of uniformed men, apparently Iranian soldiers, who pat their young recruit on the back.
>
> On November 25, a video with the logo of the Islamic Republic of Iran Broadcasting (IRIB) agency circulated on Iranian websites and social media showing the boy in the Syrian border city of Abu Kamal. He said he was a “defender of the shrine,” the euphemism the Iranian government uses for fighters it sends to Syria and Iraq.

Who did it the most seems to vary by year too, and perhaps who's reporting it. E.g. [in 2020](https://www.newarab.com/news/every-major-faction-syria-used-child-soldiers-2020), allegedly the HTS did that (according to the SNHR rather than the UN):

> Still, every major armed group in Syria used child soldiers, with radical militant group Hayat Tahrir al-Sham (HTS) recruiting the highest number.
>
> HTS' continued use of child soldiers is unsurprising, given they have "established training camps for children, enrolled them in sharia courses in an effort to… direct them to take up arms and fight", the Syrian Network for Human Rights (SNHR) said in a November 2020 report. [...]
>
> In late March 2020, HTS-affiliated Telegram channels shared a stylised video of children - some of whom looked to be no older than 11 - hoisting rifles and participating in a training exercise. A HTS spokesperson disavowed the video, saying the group does not recruit children.
>
> The SDF, while it continued to use child soldiers, recruited less than half of the number it did in 2019: 119 children in 2020, versus 283 in 2019. Starting in 2014, the SDF has signed multiple treaties with the UN and Swiss Humanitarian organisation Geneva Call to end the use of child soldiers, but has yet to fully abandon the practice. [...]
>
> In May 2020, the Turkish-backed SNA issued a ban on soldiers in its ranks aged under 18, but child recruitment still continues, as the UN and others noted. [...]
>
> A May 2020 report by Syrians for Truth and Justice describes how one 16-year old child was recruited into a government-affiliated militia, seemingly to help his family survive after the death of his father in one of Syria's detention centres.